# AWS credentials in Dockerfile

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3

I require files to be downloaded from AWS S3 during container build, however I've been unsuccessful to provide the AWS credentials to the build process without actually hardcoding them in the Dockerfile. I get the error:

> docker fatal error: Unable to locate credentials

despite previously having executed:

> aws configure

Moreover, I was not able to use --build-arg for this purpose.

My question: is it possible to have these credentials **in build time** without hardcoding them in the Dockerfile and if so how?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Can you put the creds into environment variables and assign them that way?

Comment: I can do so by declaring ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=*  and  ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=* inside the Dockerfile. But I was not able to declare them as a --build-arg

Comment: Any reason you can't use IAM profile/role?

Comment: take a look to the [Docker Secrets documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/#simple-example-get-started-with-secrets), it may help you

Comment: The best security practice is to use IAM roles rather than using credentials, but still if you need to go the credentials route you can use the environment variables as suggested by @JoãoMatos .

Answer (score 16):

Using the `--build-arg` flag is the correct way to do it, if you don't mind that the values can be seen by everyone using `docker history`, however you must use the `ARG` directive, not the `ENV` directive to specify them in your Dockerfile.

Here is an example `Dockerfile` that I have used with AWS credentials. It takes in the aws credentials as build arguments, including a default argument for the `AWS_REGION` build argument. It then performs a basic aws action, in this case logging into ecr.

```
FROM <base-image>:latest # an image I have that has `aws` installed

ARG AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
ARG AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
ARG AWS_REGION=us-west-2

RUN aws ecr get-login --no-include-email | bash

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

You then build the image with the following command:

```
docker build -t testing --build-arg AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<Your ID Here> \
    --build-arg AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<Your Key Here> .
```

Please be aware that the values of the `--build-arg` arguments can be seen by anyone with access to the image later on using `docker history`.

Comment: in my case, using the `ARG` didn't work for me. Instead, `ENV` worked.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to hide the values from `docker history`. In order to achieve this you must use [multistage-build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/). This will make your history only visible from the second `FROM` on.

Based on Jack's snippet example:

```
FROM <base-image>:latest AS first

ARG AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
ARG AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
ARG AWS_REGION=us-west-2

[do something]

FROM <base-image>:latest

COPY --from=first /dir/file_from_first /dir/file
```

This is a way to hide all the layers created during the first `FROM`.