# How I can find file downloaded from s3 in Docker container?

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am writing Dockerfile in which trying to download file from s3 to local using aws cli and ADD those files to docker container as below following [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51824671/aws-credentials-in-dockerfile)

```
FROM nrel/energyplus:8.9.0

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        python3 \
        python3-pip \
        python3-setuptools \
        groff \
        less \
    && pip3 install --upgrade pip \
    && apt-get clean

RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install --upgrade awscli

ADD . /var/simdata
WORKDIR /var/simdata

ARG AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
ARG AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
ARG AWS_REGION=ap-northeast-1

RUN aws s3 cp s3://file/to/path .

RUN mkdir -p /var/simdata

ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash" ]
```

After running `docker build -it <container id>`, I expected that I can find the file downloaded from s3 in container, but I could not.
Does anyone know where I can find this file downloaded from s3?

Answer (score 1):

The file should be in /var/simdata.

Since you do not change your work dir before downloading the file from s3, your image uses nrel/energyplus:8.9.0 default work dir.

```
$ docker pull nrel/energyplus:8.9.0
$ docker inspect --format '{{.ContainerConfig.WorkingDir}}' nrel/energyplus:8.9.0
/var/simdata
```

Comment: Could you supplement information how I can copy file in s3 file to the container I built? More specifically, I would like to copy file from s3 into /var/simdata in container. I tried to change working directory before file is downloaded from s3 as shown above Dockerfile. But I still cannot find file downloaded from s3

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be download the file to your local from s3 and in Dockerfile copy that file to /var/simdata

```
COPY file /var/simdata/file
```

This will give you more control.